# How to edit xyz F-Curves at once?

Tags: fcurves

Is there a way to edit/move multiple f-curves (xyz) at once?

I am editing a Cube and got it to scale up.
To get a feel for the right timing, I'd like to edit all xyz f-curves at once during playback.
Possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When using graph editor, one useful workflow is to select the channels you want to edit (in my example X scale, Y scale and Z scale) and press Shift H to hide all others channels (the same can be accomplished by clicking on the view eyes icons).

Then box select the keyframes to edit. Press G, X, move mouse, Enter, to move them along time. G, Y, move mouse, Enter, to move them along value.

You can even rotate and scale them using the pivot point selected by the pivot drop down menu: Individual origin to scale their bezier control points, 2D cursor to scale their values, setting the 2D cursor in the appropriate position (in my example 2D cursor is at frame 20, value 0).

Right click on the keyframes to change their Interpolation mode (Linear, Bezier, Constant, Easings, special fx like bounce), or to change their Bezier handle type (Free, Aligned, Vector, ....).

When finished, Alt H to unhide the hidden channels.

Check the useful Graphkit paid addon to speed up some common operations on multiple keyframes (Amplify, reduce, fade, distribute, cycle, repeat, .....).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key to the default behavior is in how you setup the first two keyframes.

Let's say that in the first keyframe you have x/y/z scale at 1.000

Then in the second keyframe you have x/y/z scale at 2.000

Then naturally your curves geometrically follow the same rate of change.
Blender somehow decides to lock this on you though, and when you try to edit one axis in the Graph editor the other two follow.

If this is not desired you can always make a slight change in the 3D view's  >> Properties Region >> Transform >> Then x/y/z scale. If you don't see this, with your mouse cursor over the 3D view hit <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle.

If you have a differing starting scenario (your axis values aren't all the same), you can still achieve similar behavior by using the Normalize toggle within the Graph Editor.

[image]

This will visually group the graph curves together for you to edit them as one curve.

This however will fix your offsets from one axis channel to the other, and may not be the desired effect depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

To solve that you can always use your 2D cursor options to control where to base action from.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rick Riggs for your elaborate answer!  Unfortunately so far it didnt help me due to my noobishness.  I hope I'll grasp it later on.    Cheers!